# Scala equivalent way of Range to on custom class

Tags: scala, kotlin

Recently looking at Kotlin and you can do `..` or `to` on some custom classes instead of `Int` or others.

Kotlin achieves that through an extension function as follow:

`operator fun <T: Comparable<T>> T.rangeTo(that: T): ClosedRange<T>`

which means as long as your class implements `Comparable` interface you can get that for free so you can do:

`val now = LocalDate.now()
val vacation = now..now.plusDays(10)`

I found that's quite convenient. Just wondering how can we do it in Scala, I know somehow we should achieve it through type class? Maybe right or wrong.

Can anyone showed me the simplest way to do it in Scala? Looks like there is no built in at least for `LocalDate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can always use the old pimp-my-library pattern to add `Range`-like methods to classes of interest.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

implicit class LocalDateRange(start: LocalDate) {
  // Note: LocalDate already has an until() method so can't add that here
  def to(end: LocalDate): IndexedSeq[LocalDate] =
    IndexedSeq.iterate( start
                      , ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end.plusDays(1L)).toInt
                      )(_.plusDays(1L))
}
```

Usage:

```
val now = LocalDate.now()
val vacation: IndexedSeq[LocalDate] = now to now.plusDays(10)
```

I chose `IndexedSeq[]` because [the Scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) says that `Range` is "a special case of an indexed sequence" so it seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Scala doesn't provide interval like class as Kotlin `Range`. There are several alternatives:

- Write your own interval class
- Use guava range
- Use tuple as range, but manage it yourself

Comment: Yes, it does, just only for `Int`: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html

Comment: Scala `Range` is a container, not interval